Two different dipoles attached to three trees
I wish to erect two separate antennas, one 20 meter dipole and one 40 meter dipole. My property has 3 trees that are the correct distance apart from each other. They are oriented such that when the dipoles are in place, one end of each dipole will be connected to opposite sides the same tree (the middle tree) and the two antennas will be at a 90 degree right angle to each other. They could easily be at different heights above ground.
My question is, will having one end of each antenna being only about two feet apart and being at almost perfectly 90 degrees to each other cause any problems?
Thanks!

My gut feeling is that they will be fine. You slso might consider a fan dipole, where both antennas are parallel to each other, spaced apart, and are fed with the same feedline.

@Dereck That's why I suggested a fan dipole. However, it's possible that he's doing it to cover different directions (areas) on each band.

If I had EZNEC working here, I would have modeled  the two antennas. :-)

Also, you feed each leg of BOTH dipoles to create an off-center-fed 60m dipole. With the legs at 90º, you'll have an eccentric radiation pattern that may or may not be useful, but fun to experiment with!

Derek, I have never heard of this. How would I do this? The thing is, space restraints force me to use a right angle. I have the 3 trees I can use, and they are oriented like three corners of a square. I'm only interested in 40 and 20 meters. I have no use for 60m. Thanks!

It sounds like your trees are a little too close together. If you're going to be transmitting with these antennas, keep in mind that the ends of the dipole are high-impedance points — high voltage and tiny current. You really don't want these points within one foot of a (grounded) tree trunk.
Your antennas should be constructed with an insulator at each end, with enough support wire attaching it to the tree to keep the active end well away from the tree and its foliage.
If you do this, your actual question becomes moot.

Well, this is kind of obvious. I just assumed it was implied that there is extra room between the trees for the insulating support wires.

So then what exactly did you mean by "one end of each antenna being only about two feet apart"?
